# Not able to pass empty string from UI in query parameter of url.even if in code I have passed as " "

Tags: javascript

[image]

Not able to pass empty string  from UI in query parameter of url. Even if in code I have passed as " "

```
url=this.groupbyFields += '&filter' + '[' + `${jsonData.columnName}` + ']' + '[EQ]=' + `${jsonData.fieldName === 'Unassigned' ? '': jsonData.fieldName}`;
```

Comment: Why do you think it's not sending an empty string?

Comment: But it **is** empty value. What you expect to see?

Comment: In post request if we send empty string it shows something like data:" " in pay load.So here also it should show " "